Macro that expands to value or empty, based on boolean argument
I'm generating some compile-time code. I need to append a suffix to a generated function name, based on a macro boolean. The suffix is either present or empty. How to do that?
#define FUNC_NAME(name, hasSuffix) name ## MAYBE_SHOW_SUFFIX(hasSuffix)

FUNC_NAME(foo, true);  // would generate: foo_
FUNC_NAME(foo, false); // would generate: foo


"macro boolean": What exactly do you mean with that? What kind of useful boolean evaluation are you expecting to be able to do?

Also, what you want to do, even if we take only the exact example you present, is not not possible with the preprocessor. You can't do anything conditional on the value of tokens given to a macro as argument. Macros are only token replacement.

There are no keywords in macros.

Use the fact that the result of a macro expansion is expanded again:
#define WITHSUFFIX_true(name) name ## _
#define WITHSUFFIX_false(name) name

#define FUNC_NAME(name, hasSuffix) WITHSUFFIX_ ## hasSuffix(name)

FUNC_NAME(foo, true);  // would generate: foo_
FUNC_NAME(foo, false); // would generate: foo

Result
foo_;
foo;

https://godbolt.org/z/EEM938jx9
Note that this only works because it expands the macro WITHSUFFIX_true or WITHSUFFIX_false given the condition true or false exactly. It won't work for other values like 1 or !0 or similar.

A somewhat over-engineered alternative would be to instead allow these two forms (and these forms only):
FUNC_NAME(foo, suffix);
FUNC_NAME(foo);

Where  suffix could be anything you want the caller to type out when calling the macro, true etc.

We can write this as:
#define FUNC_NAME(name, ...) FUNC ## __VA_ARGS__(name, __VA_ARGS__)

In case there are no arguments, __VA_ARGS__ boils down into nothing. Otherwise it turns into whatever the caller typed there, hopefully suffix which is the only valid input here (or there will be compiler errors).
Then we define one macro called when there were no extra parameters, which just calls the function:
#define FUNC(name, ...) name ()

And one macro which appends the suffix. Assuming we have some macro #define SUFFIX _, we need some helper macros for expansion before token concatenation:
#define CONCAT(a,b) a ## b
#define CONCAT_EXPAND(a,b) CONCAT(a,b)

#define FUNCsuffix(name, ...) CONCAT_EXPAND(name, SUFFIX) ()


Full example:
#include <stdio.h>

void foo  (void) { puts(__func__); }
void foo_ (void) { puts(__func__); }

#define SUFFIX _

#define CONCAT(a,b) a ## b
#define CONCAT_EXPAND(a,b) CONCAT(a,b)

#define FUNC(name, ...) name ()
#define FUNCsuffix(name, ...) CONCAT_EXPAND(name, SUFFIX) ()

#define FUNC_NAME(name, ...) FUNC ## __VA_ARGS__(name, __VA_ARGS__)

int main (void)
{
  FUNC_NAME(foo, suffix);
  FUNC_NAME(foo);
}

Output:
foo_
foo

